# confusing Logical operation if(null)

Tags: javascript

```
const selectedOption = { value: null , ...other }
if (selectedOption && selectedOption.value ) {
 console.log('it is?')
}
```

i think console must not occur
but it is occur  why?

### selectedOption.value is null so it is falsy value no?

---

sorry i was ediot my mistake

Comment: I get no console log. What is in `other`? Does it have a `value` property?

Comment: @MarkMeyer - Oh, wow, I totally missed that. Maybe worth an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `null` is a falsy value. The falsy values are `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`. All other values are truthy.

**But**, as [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3874623/mark-meyer) points out [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55205721/confusing-logical-operation-ifnull/55205745#comment97147659_55205721), that **doesn't** necessarily mean that you won't go into the body of the `if`, since `selectedOption.value` may not be `null` (e.g., if `other` has a non-`null` `value`):

```js
const other = {value: 42};
const selectedOption = { value: null , ...other }
if (selectedOption && selectedOption.value ) {
 console.log('it is?')
}
```

`selectedOption.value` **would** definitely be `null` if the spread were in a different order:

```js
const other = {value: 42};
const selectedOption = { ...other, value: null }
if (selectedOption && selectedOption.value ) {
  console.log('it is?');
} else {
  console.log("definitely false");
}
```

Object initializers are processed in source-code order, so later properties win over earlier ones with the same name.